# C# WPF app packed to a nuget package cannot be installed

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget-package

I've been recently looking into some sort of a automatic deployment solution for a C# WPF application. From what I understand, it is not possible to use normal methods (Dockerizing the project and setting up a DevOps infrastructure), so I've turned to other methods.

I found Squirrel.Windows and it appears to be a somewhat stable solution (in comparison to ClickOnce). One of the steps is to make your application into a nuget package, and I've successfully done that (by using the csproj file) however, the resulted setup files cannot be installed, due to a missing ".NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.9 x64".. however, it is installed, and other apps using 6.0.9 are working, so I'm completely baffled by this.

If anyone knows how to solve this or even troubleshoot this, please let me know.

I've been trying to solve this for the better part of a week, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to accomplish.
But if I understand correctly you want to
install a WPF app on some specific Windows device and make it more portable?

1. You can use ClickOnce to make an installation file.
2. You can make installer of your app https://medium.com/@kanchanaj/how-to-create-a-windows-installer-setup-file-for-desktop-application-using-visual-studio-2017-beb13015fb58 (add installer project type in Visual Studio, usually it does not go with initial installation)
3. You can make squashed .exe of your app just to run it with 1 file, without installation you have everything squashed in 1 .exe file.
   For that purpose I used to use this library: https://github.com/Fody/Costura

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) which is a deployment technology that enables you to create self-updating Windows desktop applications that can be installed and run with minimal user interaction and/or [MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/overview?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) which is the modern app package format for Windows apps.

There should be no reason use to package your app as a NuGet package and use Squirrel these days.

MSIX is the modern and recommended way to deploy desktop apps on Windows today but it comes with some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-prepare).

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/june/devops-msix-the-modern-way-to-deploy-desktop-apps-on-windows?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) may be useful.